Hover Issue with D3 Ribbon Path in Safari
I'm experiencing an issue with D3.js ribbons in Safari where certain SVG path elements don't respond to hover events for styling changes. The hover effect, such as changing the fill style, works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. However, in Safari, some paths seem to completely ignore the hover interaction.
I've tried all possible pointer-events values (all, auto, visiblePainted, etc.), but it still doesn't work. Here's what I've already verified:

The paths are visible and rendered correctly.
There are no overlapping elements obstructing the paths.
The hover effects is applied via D3's .on("mouseover", ...).

Here’s how I’m implementing the path drawing:
// Dimensions and container setup
const width = 600, height = 600;
const svg = d3.select("#circos-plot")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

// Updated data with new angles
const data = {
    source: { radius: 200, startAngle: 0.10082134423424959, endAngle: 0.23383773956851167 },
    target: { radius: 200, startAngle: 1.0174690537411528, endAngle: 1.0615254394569593 }
};

// Ribbon generator
const ribbon = d3.ribbon().radius(data.source.radius);

// Append ribbon with hover event
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", ribbon)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("class", "ribbon")  // Add class for hover styling
    .style("pointer-events", "visibleFill")  // Ensure pointer events work
    .on("mouseover", function(event, d) {
      // Change color on hover
      d3.select(this).transition().duration(300).attr("fill", "orange");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(event) {
      // Reset color when mouse leaves
      d3.select(this).transition().duration(300).attr("fill", "steelblue");
    });

Below is the complete working example:
https://codepen.io/joko3ono/pen/VYZPwWa
And here is the GIF showcasing the bug.
gif
Is there any specific code or adjustments needed to make the SVG behave correctly in Safari, similar to how it works in other browsers?



        // Dimensions and container setup
        const width = 600, height = 600;
        const svg = d3.select("#circos-plot")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

        // Data for the ribbon
        const data = {
            source: { radius: 200, startAngle: 0.1, endAngle: 0.23 },
            target: { radius: 200, startAngle: 1.01, endAngle: 1.06 }
        };

        // Ribbon generator
        const ribbon = d3.ribbon().radius(data.source.radius);

        // 1. Add the visible ribbon path
        const ribbonPath = svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("d", ribbon)
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .attr("class", "ribbon");

        // 2. Add an invisible overlay path for hover interaction
        const invisibleRibbonPath = svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("d", ribbon)
            .attr("fill", "none") // No fill for the overlay
            .attr("stroke", "transparent") // Invisible stroke
            .attr("stroke-width", 20) // Expand the hoverable area
            .style("pointer-events", "stroke") // Interact only with the stroke
            .on("mouseover", function(event) {
                ribbonPath.transition().duration(300).attr("fill", "orange");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(event) {
                ribbonPath.transition().duration(300).attr("fill", "steelblue");
            });
.ribbon {
            transition: fill 0.3s ease;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="circos-plot"></svg>




The key takeaway from your response is:
#circos-plot {  border: 1px solid #ccc;  }
I'm not sure why adding a border to the SVG element causes it to be filled, but some elements still don't respond to hover. I've added a GIF to the question to illustrate the issue.

I have updated the code based on the issue observed in the GIF file and added comments in the code. Please try it out; I believe it should work for you. @joko3ono


The overlay path (d) is an exact duplicate of the ribbon's shape.
Ensures interactions are tied to the ribbon’s geometry.
The stroke-width of the overlay is set to 20, expanding the clickable or hoverable area beyond the ribbon's edges.
Invisible stroke ensures it doesn’t affect the visible ribbon.

